# Can I get dbutils.fs.cp to have the same behaviour as *nix cp?

Tags: databricks

If I perform the following on *nix:

```bash
mkdir -p a/1
mkdir -p b/2
cp -r b a/
```

I get the following output:

```bash
tree a
a
├── 1
└── b
    └── 2
```

I attempted to do the same thing with dbutils:

```bash
dbutils.fs.mkdirs('dbfs:/tmp/a/1')
dbutils.fs.mkdirs('dbfs:/tmp/b/2')

dbutils.fs.cp(
  'dbfs:/tmp/b', 
  'dbfs:/tmp/a/', 
  True)

dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/tmp/a')
```

However, I get the following behaviour:

```bash
[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/a/1/', name='1/', size=0, modificationTime=1670871337000),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/a/2/', name='2/', size=0, modificationTime=1670871337000)]
```

Can I get dbutils.fs.cp to have the same behaviour as *nix cp?